# Android application installation on an older version via eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, installation, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am a complete newbie to android development, though I know a thing or two about programming. I was trying to install an app that I had developed (a single .java file) in eclipse on my gingerbread phone, but the eclipse IDE fails to recognize my phone as a VALID device to install the app. Maybe because I have developed it in ADT 16 (4.1). Is there any way  to install the app on my phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the Minimum Version of your Android App, Right Click on the Project, Go to Properties, Select android & Change the Version from android 4.1 to the Version of your mobile Device. 
 Clean the Project & Run Again, Copy the new *.apk to android, It should work now